# React native app doesnot render on restart after closing the app using back button

Tags: android, react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-native-router-flux

I am using react-native-router-flux, react-redux and redux in my application. So, when I close the app using back button and then open the app again nothing loads as in no life cycle methods are getting executed but the functions which i have binded to the routes to execute onenter they execute and sets the state with reducer.

Comment: have you found any solution yet!